# Golang : After installed revel command tool, not working properly

Tags: go, revel

[image: Tried in Git Bash]

[image: Tried in windows cmd]

Here I followed revel FW document and installed successfully. But try to use revel command in both Git bash and cmd, it is not working

Please anyone give some suggestion for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run: go get github.com/revel/revel
2. Run: go get github.com/revel/cmd/revel
3. Now revel should be available from any place. If not, make sure you have $GOPATH/bin set.

P.S.
If have problems installing github.com/revel/cmd/revel, try removing completely github.com/revel, and re-installing both packages.

Comment: I made that issue. Added incorrect Environment variables.